# libsvm predicting same value for all data set instances

Tags: libsvm

I am Using libsvm C# wrapper for svr to predict Salary .predicted results are wrong. libsvm is giving same value for all the instances.i have  preform grid search parameter selection.how can i solve this issue here is my code.

```cs
Problem train = Problem.Read(@"H:\test.csv");
Problem test = Problem.Read(@"H:\testsvmf1.csv");


//For this example (and indeed, many scenarios), the default
//parameters will suffice.
Parameter parameters = new Parameter();
//double C;
//double Gamma;


//This will do a grid optimization to find the best parameters
//and store them in C and Gamma, outputting the entire
//search to params.txt.

ParameterSelection.Grid(train, parameters, @"H:\params.txt", out C, out Gamma);
parameters.C = 512;
parameters.Gamma = 0.5;
parameters.SvmType = SvmType.NU_SVR;
double cv = Training.PerformCrossValidation(train,parameters,10);

Console.Write(cv);
//Train the model using the optimal parameters.

Model model = Training.Train(train, parameters);


//Perform classification on the test data, putting the
//results in results.txt.

Prediction.Predict(test, @"H:\resultsnew1.txt", model, false);

}

public static SvmType NU_SVR { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you perform a grid search to tune your parameters, but then you set them manually to fixed values (C=512,Gamma=0.5). The fixed parameters are used for training...